# Nested perl matching groups not working?

Tags: perl

I want the following code to print out "bye", and then print out "hello". However, when I run it, it prints out "bye" and then perl tells me that $str2 has not been initialized.

```
 my $item = "hello/bye";
 if($item =~ m/.*(bye)/g){
     my $str1 = $1;
     print "$str1\n";
     my $str2 = ($item =~ m/(hello).*/g)[0];
     print "$str2\n";
 }
```

I think that there is probably something I do not understand about the m//g part, but I am having trouble finding my answer in the perldoc page for perlre.

Comment: `if (//g)` makes no sense. Drop the `g`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
if($item =~ m/.*(bye)/g)
```

that does not reset the match iterator (we are in scalar context). The "position" remains at the character after the `bye` substring. So the following `m//g` picks up from there the previous one left off.

You can verify this yourself:

```
if ($item =~ /(bye)/g) {
    printf "pos \$item = %d\n", pos $item;
    ...
}
```

which will print `pos $item =9`.

Incidentally `$item =~ /.*(bye)/` is better written as `$item =~ /(bye)/` (assuming you don't care if you match the first or the last `bye` substring, just that `$item` has `bye` somewhere). Similarly, `$item =~ /(hello).*/` is better written as `$item =~ /(hello)/`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $item = "hello/bye";

if ($item =~ /(bye)/) {
     my $str1 = $1;
     print "$str1\n";
     my $str2 = ($item =~ /(hello)/g)[0];
     print "$str2\n";
 }
```

Comment: You're getting very close to the t-shirt and mug. :)

Comment: *"`$item =~ /.*(bye)/` is better written as `$item =~ /(bye)/`"* It's worth underlining that these *aren't* the same: the former will capture the *last* occurrence of `bye`, while the latter will capture the *first*.

Comment: Is there a way to reset the match iterator? Say, if I wanted to iterate through the same string with different regexes?

Comment: @SunT I am not sure I understand. The obvious solution is not to use `/g` in scalar context. But you could do `pos $item = undef`.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for pointing that out. I had implicitly assumed that all that mattered was that there was a `bye` substring somewhere in `$item`.